# Asking User to enter Text File (ASCII) Name while creating it in C++

Tags: c++, console-application

i want to have user input the name of file (not binary file, but its a text file) in C++ console application (WINDOWS 7) , after user enter name in a char name[10] variable, i want to assign this name to the text file

```
fout.open("<user_name_here>.txt",ios::out); 

> where <user_name_here> is a name entered by user
```

please answer the question considering me as a beginner. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cin can be used to read from the standard input (keyboard).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
   string name;
   cin >> name; //name should not contain whitespaces/tabs etc

   ofstream out_file;
   out_file.open (name.c_str());
   out_file << "I am writing something to the file";
   out_file.close();
}
```